# Automatically convert date string format for post API

Tags: angular, angular5

My project includes many date fields.
A the time of Post request Api,format required by the server is 
"YYYY-MM-DD"
But the format which i want to show in UI is "DD-MM-YYYY"

I am familiar with moment library and its functions to change date into string and vice versa and other functions.

**I don't want to do conversion process for each date field.**
(change in component by moment library).

Is there any by which i can achieve my requirement.

I have no problem in binding my input with text **string**

At UI this should show : DD-MM-YYYY

AT post format of string should be:  YYYY-MM-DD

Restrictions:

1. I cant define new Object in my modal. But getter and setter are 
   allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is around [HttpInterceptors](https://v4.angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses).

Interceptor layer is between your UI logic and the backend. You can transform request parameters and response data in it.

Examples:

- example of transforming request [ref](https://v4.angular.io/guide/http#setting-new-headers)
- example of handling response: [ref](https://v4.angular.io/guide/http#logging)

Now, just handle your data at this level.

Ideas on how you can handle it:

- recursively pass your object and change date formats with momentjs lib
- use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<object>))` approach

probably 2nd is faster, but it is up to your specific of course.

You can specify replace function when using `JSON.stringify`. You can find more verbose explanations in the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). So you can pass the replacer function and replace your dates there.

Anyway you need to detect somehow that you need to change date format of that property. You can do this using regexps.

Comment: I suggested you how to change formats in the model. Of course you can do this in directive or anywhere.

Comment: I know moment conversion methods and handling api response..but how ng model binded string will change at time of post request

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with this interceptor that changes the javascript Date object to a string.

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { DateService } from '../../shared/services/date/date.service';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor {

  constructor(private _dateService: DateService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let body;

    if (req.responseType !== 'json' || !req.body ||
      (req.method !== 'POST' && req.method !== 'PUT')) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    if (_.isArray(req.body)) {
      body = Object.assign([], req.body);
    } else {
      body = Object.assign({}, req.body);
    }

    this.changeRequest(body);
    let reqClone = req.clone({ body });
    return next.handle(reqClone);
  }

  private changeRequest(body) {
    if (body && typeof body === 'object') {
      Object.entries(body).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => {
          if (typeof value !== 'string' && _.size(value)) {
            this.changeRequest(value);
          } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Date]') {
            body[key] = this._dateService.toString(value);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }

}
```

I also create a simple DateService using moment:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/en-gb';

@Injectable()
export class DateService {

  constructor() {
    moment.locale('en-gb');
  }

  toString(date: any, format: string = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'): string {
    return date !== null ? moment(date).format(format) : null;
  }

}
```

I hope this helps.